# Find last line matching a pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I am running multiple data collectors scripts that extracts data from social platform. Each logs the progress in their own log file. I have to monitor them manually using the ps command.

I want to make a script in bash which on executing tells me if the collector is running or stopped. According to my plan, it will go into the log file, skip to the end and then search the log upward  for the keywords like:
1. if collector is running, log file says **Processing Line**; 
2. if collector is stopped , log file says **Exception**;

It will the search the file upward to get latest occurrence of any 2 of the above cases. 
I want it to stop searching the log file when it has found either one of these.
And then i will echo the status.

Currently i am able to skip to the end and then search it upwards, but i don't know how to make the search stop if it finds any one of the lines containing the searched patterns first.? And how will **if else** will be implemented according to this?

My code is

```
cat **LogFile** | grep -E 'Processing line|Exception' | tail -1
```

Comment: `cat LogFile | grep -E 'Processing Line|Exception' | tail -1` will show the last line of LogFile containing 'Processing Line' or 'Exception' and then stop – what else do you need?

Comment: `tac logfile | grep -m 1 -E 'Processing Line|Exception'` is potentially more efficient, depending on how `tac` is implemented.

Comment: @MarioZannone: Maybe he needs instruction on avoiding charges of UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`)?  The `grep` command is perfectly capable of opening the file.

Comment: Ok i get it what you guys mean, but just one question: How would the bash tell me which one did it found 'Processing line' or 'Exception'? And how will i implement if else to print the status? For exp: say it found exception first  than processing line, on what base should i say echo " Collector Stopped". etc

Answer (score 0):

```
# using tac
tac /etc/passwd | awk '/Processing Line/{print "Processing Line found...\n" $0;exit}
                       /Exception/{print "Exception found...\n" $0;exit}'

# Using awk
awk '{line[NR]=$0}         # Store all lines into an array, use NR (line number) as element
 END{for(i=NR;i>0;i--)     # loop through array in reverse
       {if(line[i] ~ /Processing Line/) # Exit on match
          {print "Processing Line found...\n" line[i];exit}
       else if(line[i] ~ /Exception/)
          {print "Exception found...\n" line[i];exit}
       }
    }' /etc/passwd
```